# Database Design for Facebook "likes"

Tags: database, facebook, database-design

New to database design and I was wondering how to efficiently design something like Facebook likes with future scalability in mind.

Let's say you have 3 tables: users, photos and albums.
Let's say a user can like either a photo or an album.

**Should I use 1 table for both types of likes?** 
This would probably mean it would have an user_id, like_type(0-photo, 1-album etc), like_value(the id value of whatever content it is, whether it is photo_id or album_id)?

**or have 2 different tables for each likes** (ex. photos_likes and albums_likes)?
which would only contain user_id and photo/album_id

I want to make sure that the database design is clean and semi-scaleproof whether we add many more objects in the future(videos, comments, notes, etc) or have a ton of likes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could try a inherited table approach see [implementing table inheritence](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/implementing-table-inheritance-in-sql-server) for more indepth detail.

But essentially it works just like inheritence in code, you have a base table 'Like' and then tables which 'inherit' from it 'CommentLike', 'PhotoLike' etc.

See attached diagram for a quick mockup.

[image: Example of table design]

Comment: Note: the id of the parent table and child would be the same, it is used as a 'foreign key' in these cases. (Read the blog post from SqlTeam)

Answer (score 3):

Two different tables. This way if you ever have an object that you want to add likes to later you can just make a new table "object_likes" and store the likes there.

If you wanted to store them all in one table, you would need a type table, which would store all the types of objects, and in your like table you would have to reference the type_id. This would let you add types later.

To me the first method is much better.

Comment: Additionally it would save space if the amount of data becomes large. Having one table would lead to row's having useless data for the columns referring to types that are set to zero for example.